# Conditional running tally sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I play basketball and want to tally my points under certain conditions. I never play on Sat or Sun, though I do not always play every week day.

If I miss a week day session, my tally resets. If I lose, my rally resets. If I win on a Friday and win the following Monday, my tally should continue.

Here is a sample result set:

```
|       Date | Points | Won_Flag | Tally |
|------------|--------|----------|-------|
| 2015-07-23 |     18 |    false |     0 |
| 2015-07-24 |      7 |     true |     7 |
| 2015-07-28 |     10 |     true |    10 |
| 2015-07-29 |     20 |     true |    30 |
| 2015-07-30 |     11 |    false |     0 |
| 2015-07-31 |     18 |     true |    18 |
| 2015-08-01 |     31 |     true |    31 |
| 2015-09-14 |      0 |    false |     0 |
| 2015-09-15 |      8 |     true |     8 |
| 2015-09-16 |     13 |    false |     0 |
| 2015-09-17 |      9 |     true |     9 |
| 2015-09-18 |      1 |     true |    10 |
| 2015-09-21 |      7 |     true |    17 |
| 2015-09-22 |     15 |    false |     0 |
| 2015-10-01 |      9 |    false |     0 |
| 2015-10-02 |      5 |     true |     5 |
| 2015-10-05 |     14 |     true |    19 |
| 2015-10-13 |      3 |     true |     3 |
| 2015-10-14 |     14 |     true |    17 |
| 2015-10-15 |     12 |     true |    29 |
| 2015-10-16 |      8 |     true |    37 |
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28faf/2/0)

Comment: You should edit your question and put sample data and desired results in the question as text (use "{}" or four spaces at the beginning of the line to format it).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a cumulative sum and `lag()`.  Use `lag()` to determine if the tally needs to restart.  Then accumulate this flag to get a group identifier that can be used for a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*, sum(tally) over (partition by grp order by date) as cumeTally
from (select t.*, sum(tallyStartFlag) over (order by date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when lag(date) over (order by date)) = datedd(day, -1, date) and
                              datename(weekday, date) in ('Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')
                         then 0
                         when lag(date) over (order by date) = dateadd(day, -3, date) and
                              datename(weekday, date) = 'Monday'
                         then 0
                         else 1
                    end) as tallyStartFlag
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Handling the weekend days is a bit tricky.

EDIT:

I missed the part about losing.  That is pretty easy to incorporate:

```
select t.*, sum(case when won_flag then tally else 0 end) over (partition by grp order by date) as cumeTally
from (select t.*, sum(tallyStartFlag) over (order by date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   (case when won_flag = false
                         then 0
                         when lag(date) over (order by date)) = datedd(day, -1, date) and
                              datename(weekday, date) in ('Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')
                         then 0
                         when lag(date) over (order by date) = dateadd(day, -3, date) and
                              datename(weekday, date) = 'Monday'
                         then 0
                         else 1
                    end) as tallyStartFlag
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: There are some syntax errors. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28faf/3/0) is the corrected version.

Comment: It does not solve the problem, imho. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/28faf/10) are some adjustments.